# Passing make variables to shell script as arguments to the shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, makefile

From make i invoke a script:

/myshell_script.sh "Make_var1" "Make_var2"

I extract the variables in shell script by using $1 $2
The variables I receive are empty. These are received as shell variables. I want the variables to be passed as make variable arguments.

Comment: Post an example with the expected output and what actually happens.

Comment: Post a **complete** example, I still have no idea what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
./myscript.sh  %argument%

Comment: I invoked the shell file with the make variable /shell_script.sh $(make_var1) . This worked.